# Add the mouse cursor in input field to the upper left corner

Tags: html, css

How can I add a cursor to the top left corner in the input field. 
[image]

My field is a standard TextInput field generated by an external library. I enlarged them by adding style:

```
.input-xlarge,
input.select2-search__field {
  height: 100px;
  <!-- I will set the text in the upper left corner -->
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  line-height: 1em;
  padding: 0 0 400px 0;
}
```

But it doesn't work properly. The field is enlarged, but the cursor is in the center, not in the upper left corner.

```css
.input-xlarge,
input.select2-search__field {
  height: 100px;
  <!-- I will set the text in the upper left corner -->padding-top: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  line-height: 1em;
  padding: 0 0 400px 0;
}
```

```html
<select name="tags" class="form-control django-select2" placeholder="Opis..." required id="id_tags" data-allow-clear="false" data-minimum-input-length="0" multiple>
  <option value="1">one</option>

  <option value="2">two</option>

  <option value="3">three</option>

  <option value="4">oneA</option>

</select>


<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/django_select2/django_select2.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you reproduce that at snippet?

Comment: I was editing my question

Comment: text-align: left - does not work for the example given

Comment: Can you please update the snippet to look like the screenshot you shared?